# OCR of bit blurry text using AWS Rekognition or Google Vision API

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, google-vision, amazon-rekognition

Is there any way how to improve text extraction confidence of bit blurry text using AWS Rekognition or Google Vision api.

Is there any way to train model for text detection from blurry text document using AWS rekognition or Google Vision api?

Comment: You need to play around with `word confidence filter`. It basically helps you remove results which might be unreliable due to being blurry/smudged.

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.